# How to modify org headline font face based on WIP/TODO etc?

Tags: org-mode, syntax-highlighting

I have DOING defined as a DONE state. (Odd, I know.) I'm trying to get the font face for the DOING headline to appear the same as DONE. How can I do this?  (Using Doom.)

[image]

Comment: Can you add to your question how you define the `DOING` state? Is it a `TODO` state or a `DONE` state?

Comment: @NickD question updated to include state.

Comment: Yeah, that was confusing :-) I expected it to be a `TODO` state.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Customize the variable `org-todo-keywords` and include `DOING` in the same sequence as `DONE`, and/or customize the variable `org-todo-keyword-faces` to set the appearance of `DOING`.  The latter solution (customizing `org-todo-keyword-faces`) gives Org no persistent association between `DOING` and `DONE`; in other words, if the appearance of `DONE` changes, `DOING` will not change until you go in to make it match again. The former solution (customizing `org-todo-keywords`) should be sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

[I believe that @gusbrs had offered the correct solution but he deleted his answer. I hope he undeletes it, but for the time being, I'm posting his answer in his stead: I will happily delete this answer if he undeletes his.]

Set `org-fontify-done-headline` to `nil`:

```
(setq org-fontify-done-headline nil)
```

or use `Customize` to do the same thing permanently.

The doc string of the variable says:

> Non-nil means change the face of a headline if it is marked DONE.
> Normally, only the TODO/DONE keyword indicates the state of a headline.
> When this is non-nil, the headline after the keyword is set to the
> ‘org-headline-done’ as an additional indication.

Its default value is `t`, so the whole headline's face is changed for better visibility. If you set it to `nil`, then only the `DONE` keyword changes face.

Comment: @gusbrs I believe that what you propose here is necessary but insufficient. The same applies to my proposed answer above. I think the correct answer is both. Without my answer, DOING will not be recognized as a "done" state, and without your answer, DOING headlines will not be fontified, only the DOING keyword. Do you concur?

Comment: @PhilHudson Your accepted answer worked. So simple – and (now) obvious.

Comment: It seems I was climbing the wrong tree :-)